# How to pass Strings from one activity to another using spinner (Android Studio)

Tags: java, android, android-activity, android-spinner

I am a novice android developer trying to program my first application. I am almost done, but for the last step of the app, I want to take the selection the user made on the previous page from a spinner.

After the user chooses a string from the spinner, they press a button at the button to move to the next page. I retrieved the string from the spinner using `getItemAtPosition`, but I don't know how to pass that information to the button method so that I can use intent to pass it to the next activity. I know I could get rid of the button entirely and go to the next activity once the user has selected a string from the spinner, but I don't really want to do that. Here is the code below:

```
@Override
public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {
    String text = adapterView.getItemAtPosition(i).toString();
}

@Override
public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> adapterView) {

}

public void quoteButton(View view){
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, DisplayQuoteActivity.class);
    startActivity(intent);
}
```

`text` is the string that the user selected and `quoteButton` is the button to jump to the next activity but I do not know how to transfer the string `text` from the `onItemSelected` method to the `quoteButton` method.

Thanks for the help.

Comment: The linked question has nothing to do with spinners.

Comment: You just need to store your selected value of spinner into global String object. And onClick of Button you have to pass that value using intent.putExtra() method, like shown in linked question.

Comment: Or Simply Add in onClick method of button, 
 intent.putExtra("key_name",spinnerObject.getSelectedItem().toString());